# calculate distance between points in different point layers

Tags: qgis, distance

I have two point layers.
Layer one contains a single point (a landmark)
Layer 2 contains a set of points (person locations)

Is there an automated means of obtaining the distance of each individual point in layer 2 from the single point in layer 1.  And can this result be filled to a field in attribute table of layer 2.

(Complete novice!)

Comment: There's the **Distance to nearest hub** tool from the _Processing Toolbox_ which you could use.

Comment: look at this: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html